# Assessing model prediction performance using tolerance interval coverage

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, prediction-interval, tolerance-interval, coverage-probability

I am trying to assess a model's prediction performance, and one metric I look at is the percentage of new observations that fall within the 95% tolerance interval, and see whether or not it is actually close to 95%. If the percentage of new observations that fall in the tolerance interval is much lower than 95%, could I conclude based on this metric, the model has poor prediction?

Is the method I described above widely used? If you know of any references, please list a few.

Please note: I look at other metrics as well, but I want to verify whether or not I can draw such a conclusion using this metric. I am **not** looking for other suggestions for assessing model prediction performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about a frequentist prediction interval or a Bayesian one? The frequentist prediction interval absolutely doesn't have to contain 95% of the new observations. The frequentist prediction *procedure* is such that, if you collect a vast amount of samples of size $N$ and for each of these samples you form the corresponding prediction interval, then about 95% of these intervals will contain **one** observation not included in the $N$ ones used to build the prediction interval.

In more formal terms, if $(X_1,\dots,X_N)=\mathbf{X}$ is a random vector with independent and identically distributed components, and if $X^*$ is another random variable independent of the components of $\mathbf{X}$ but having their same distribution, then a (frequentist) 95%-confidence prediction interval is a random interval $I(\mathbf{X})=[a(\mathbf{X}),b(\mathbf{X})]$ such that

$$P[X^*\in I(\mathbf{X})]=.95$$

This means that if I collect a sample $(x_1,\dots,x_N)=\mathbf{x}$, i.e., a *realization* of $\mathbf{X}$, and compute the corresponding prediction interval $I(\mathbf{x})$, then another observation $x^*$ may or may not belong to $I(\mathbf{x})$. However, if I were to repeat this procedure multiple times (collect sample $\mathbf{x}$; compute $I(\mathbf{x})$; collect $x^*$), then on average $I(\mathbf{x})$ would contain $x^*$ 95% of times. Note that the confidence level for a prediction *procedure* refers to the percentage of prediction intervals which contain an extra observation not used to build the intervals. It does **not** refer to the percentage of new observations that we collect! If we build an interval and collect $x^*=x_1^*$, we're 95%-confident that $I(\mathbf{x})$ will contain $x_1^*$. Now, suppose we keep collecting more new observations $x^*_2,\dots,x^*_m,\dots$: we cannot say that we are 95% confident that 95%, or 50%, or 99% or whatever percentage of the new observations will fall in $I(\mathbf{x})$. We just don't know.

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for something different: you need an interval which, 95% of times, would contain 95% of the population. In other words, you need a procedure which, for each sample $\mathbf{x}$, builds an interval $T(\mathbf{x})$ such that, for 95% of all possible samples, has the following property:

- as you keep collecting more and more observations, not used to build $T(\mathbf{x})$, the percentage of observations which falls in $T(\mathbf{x})$ tends to 95%, as the number of observations goes to $\infty$.

Of course, for a given sample $\mathbf{x}$ and corresponding interval $T(\mathbf{x})$, you cannot be sure that $T(\mathbf{x})$ will contain 95% of the population. However, you know that, if you repeat the procedure more and more times, on average 95% of the intervals will be "good". Such intervals are called *tolerance* intervals: the R package `tolerance` helps you build them.

As a final note, I personally have never heard of tolerance intervals being used to assess the predictive capability of a statistical model, but of course that doesn't mean that it has never been done, or that it's a bad idea.

PS to keep things simple, when talking about tolerance intervals I considered the confidence level of the procedure and the percentage of the population covered to be numerically equal. However, that's not needed: you can define a 95%-confidence tolerance interval for the central 50% of the population, or a 50%-confidence tolerance interval for the central 95% of the population (though I don't think anyone would ever use a 50% confidence procedure!).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and for clarifying what I am looking for. I would like to receive some further feedback on how widely used this method is. I will upvote your answer when I have enough rep...

Comment: no need for upvoting, you can just accept the answer you prefer. Concerning feedback, I cannot offer any because, as I said, I never heard of tolerance intervals being used to assess the predictive performance of a method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between a 'correct' coverage probability and predictive performance. Take e.g. as prediction interval the range from the 2.5% to the 97.5% quantile of the responses in the training set. Its coverage probability will probably not be too far away from 95% in an independent test set but the predictive power of this empty model will be poor.